# Limiting query results using TableClient.Query from Azure.Data.Tables

Tags: c#, .net, azure-table-storage

In the older API (WindowsAzure.Storage), there was the Take() method for this purpose, but it seems that has been removed in this newer API. I haven't been able to find a way to perform the same function, can someone provide an answer to this?

Comment: Please add following line `using System.Linq;`

Comment: @MarkusMeyer Thanks so much! I didn't know until now that the Take method was part of LINQ. Always assumed it was part of Azure's Table Storage API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add `linq` to the usings:

```cs
using System.Linq;
```

[MS Docs: Enumerable.Take Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=net-6.0)

> Namespace:
> System.Linq

Comment: This is a VERY BAD IDEA. Filtering should be done on the server side not on the client side! Proper example in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/data.tables-readme#query-table-entities

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$filter`, `$top` or `$select` to limit query results.

`$filter`  Returns only tables or entities that satisfy the specified filter.
Note that no more than 15 discrete comparisons are permitted within a $filter string.

`$top` Returns only the top n tables or entities from the set.

`$select` Returns the desired properties of an entity from the set.

To return the top n entities for any query, specify the $top query option. The following example returns the top 10 entities from a table named Customers:

Sample query –

```
https://myaccount.table.core.windows.net/Customers()?$top=10
```

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/querying-tables-and-entities#sample-query-expressions

Comment: But that is directly from Azure, what if I were to query using the Azure.Data.Tables package for .NET?

Comment: If your goal is to create a Linq Expression which will be translated to the proper $filter, $top, $select equivalents I have posted an example over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73772499/1209734

Answer (score 0):

The parameter you are looking for is `maxPerPage` in [`TableClient.Query`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.tables.tableclient.query?view=azure-dotnet#azure-data-tables-tableclient-query-1(system-string-system-nullable((system-int32))-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-string))-system-threading-cancellationtoken)).

From the documentation:

> **maxPerPage Nullable**
> The maximum number of entities that will be
> returned per page. Note: This value does not limit the total number of
> results if the result is fully enumerated.