# How many requests TableClient.Query<T> will make, if AsPages() is not used?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage, azure-tableclient

I have a question about `Pageable< T >` in C#. I have table storage in Azure named- Domains. I am using Azure.Data.Tables nuget package, and to Query all the domains i am using this :

```
 var domains = _localDomainTableClient
                .Query<Domain>()
                .AsPages()
                .SelectMany(d => d.Values);
```

But i dont understant something. What if i use Query< T > without AsPages method ?

```
IEnumerable<Domain> domainsPAges = tableClient.Query<Domain>();
```

I know that `AsPages()` returns a collection of pages. For example if I have 10000 items in the table, `Query<Domain>().AsPages()` should make 10 requests to the table and return me 10 pages with 1000 items in each page (unless I changed the default value) but I don't understand what exactly is happening if I don't use `AsPages() ?`

Example:

```
IEnumerable<Domain> domainsPAges = tableClient.Query<Domain>();
```

`Query<Domain>()` return `Pageble< T >` but, does it make 10 requests to the table again or does it take all the elements until the memory overflows (4 MB by default) or take all the elements at once ?

I check [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.pageable-1?view=azure-dotnet), but I couldn't find what I needed.

> A collection of values that may take multiple service requests to iterate over.

> A collection of values retrieved in pages

What is it even mean ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How many requests Query will make, if AsPages() is not used?

In C#, the Query method is part of the Azure Cosmos DB SDK.

The `Query<T>` method will retrieve all matching results in a single request to the database. This behaviour is known as a single-partition query.

If the query involves multiple partitions, then the Query method will make multiple requests to retrieve all matching results. The exact number of requests will depend on the number of partitions involved and the size of the result set.

If the `AsPages()` method is not used, then the query results will be returned as a single enumerable object. If the `AsPages()` method is used, the query results will be returned as a sequence of pages, each containing a subset of the query results. In this case, the number of requests made will depend on the size of each page and the total number of results matching the query criteria.

> What if i use Query< T > without AsPages method

In C#, if you use `Query<T>` without the AsPages method, you will receive all the results of the query in a single batch.

The `Query<T>` method returns an IEnumerable that represents the results of the query. If you do not use AsPages, the entire result set will be loaded into memory at once. This leads to high memory usage and performance can be degraded, as it can consume a lot of memory.

AsPages method also enables you to retrieve the results in a more efficient manner. It allows you to retrieve the results in smaller batches or pages, which can help reduce the memory usage and improve performance. The AsPages method returns an `IAsyncEnumerable<Page<T>>`, where each Page represents a page of results.

> Query() return Pageble< T > but, does it make 10 requests to the table again or does it take all the elements until the memory overflows (4 MB by default) or take all the elements at once?

The behaviour of Query() depends on the implementation of the method and the underlying database system.

when you execute a query that returns a pageable result, the database will execute the query and return only a subset of the results to the application, based on the page size and the current page number. The remaining results are retrieved on subsequent requests for the next pages.

So if you call `Query<Domain>()` with a specific page size, it will only retrieve the number of elements specified in that page size, and not all the elements in the table.

The number of requests made to the table will depend on the number of pages that need to be retrieved to return all the results for the query.

The memory used to store the retrieved results will depend on the size of the objects retrieved and the number of objects retrieved in each page. When using pageable results, the size of the objects returned is generally limited to reduce memory usage, so it's unlikely that the memory usage will exceed the default limit of 4 MB.

For more information refer this [Query table entities](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Data.Tables/#query-table-entities) and [SO Thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55010546/how-to-retrieve-more-than-1000-results-from-table-storage/55010645#55010645)

Comment: So if i understand correct, `tableclient.Query<Domain>()` will return all the entities from the azure table, no matter how many entities there are (5000 for example). But this can create a problem: high memory usage and performance. But will it return all the entities ?
 If i use `tableclient.Query<Domain>(maxPerPage: 500)` it will make only one request and return only the first 500 elemetns. (No 10 pages with 500 eninies each). 
And if i use `tableclient.Query<Domain>().AsPages()` it will return all the entites as pages - 5 pages with 1000 entities eaach ? (if i am using default values) ?

Comment: When you call tableclient.Query<Domain>() in Azure Table Storage, it will return all the entities that match the query, subject to some limitations on the number of entities returned per request and the total size of the response.

Comment: The Query method will return up to a maximum of 1,000 entities in a single response, and if there are more than 1,000 entities that match the query, it will return a continuation token that you can use to retrieve the next batch of entities. This means that if you have more than 1,000 entities in your table, you will need to make multiple requests to retrieve all the entities that match your query.

Comment: And It's important to note that using a smaller page size can improve performance by reducing the amount of data transferred over the network, but it may also increase the number of requests needed to retrieve all the entities that match the query. So, you should choose a page size that balances performance and the number of requests needed to retrieve all the entities you need.